# Again about arithmetic in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

There is a column that looks like this

```
1    
2    
3  
4  
5
```

It is necessary to summarize and to get a column of this type

```
3    
6    
10    
15
```

the sum of the first and second, sum of the first and second and third etc.

thanks in advance

Comment: What defines first, second or third? is there an ID column? or is it just based on the given column?

Comment: Yes there is id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use correlated query like this:

```
select (
        select sum(col)
        from your_table t2
        where t2.col <= t.col
        ) sum_col
from your_table t;
```

Produces:

```
sum_col
-------
1
3
6
10
15
```